# angular2-node-express-mongo. How to deploy front-end and backend?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, frontend, backend

I am developing a web app and I am using Angular 2 in front-end, and intending to use Nodejs-Express-MongoDB in back-end. Now that my front-end is almost done, I am moving to the back-end side, and while doing that, I was wondering how can I deploy this app? How do web/full-stack developers usually do? and what are the best practices?
Should I put both front-end code and back-end code on the same server? on separate servers? Same thing for my database?

So far the application is in its early stage and is for demonstration purposes only, not too much data to handle, but still, I would like to know what are the best practices? Thanks!

Comment: Use Docker, it's great!

Comment: Thanks @Phil. Can you point out some tutorials please?

Comment: Thanks again @Phil. You're right, Docker is great! (Y)